# How to understand python decorator arguments pass

Tags: python, decorator

I try to understand python decorator

```
def dec(func):
    def wrap(*args,**kw):
        print args, kw
        return func(*args,**kw)
    return wrap

@dec
def myfunc(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    return a+b+c


>>> myfunc()
() {}
6
>>> myfunc(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3) {}
6
>>> myfunc(1,2,c=5)
(1, 2) {'c': 5}
8
>>>
```

When I run `myfunc()` args and kw are nothing, but when I run `myfunc(1,2,3)` and `myfunc(1,2,c=5)`, args and kw were passed to `dec` function.

As I know,

```
@dec
def myfunc(...)
```

equals to `myfunc = dec(myfunc)` <-- no arguments were mentioned here.

How arguments were passed to `wrap` function in `dec`? How to understand these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if i understand correctly your problem, but the default values for `myfunc` arguments are known only to `myfunc` - your decorator has no knowledge of them, so it cannot print them.

That's why:

```
myfunc()
```

results in printing:

```
() {}
```

Both `*args` and `**kw` are empty for the decorator, but the decorated function will use the default values in this case.

In the second and third case you get the parameters printed, as they are explicitly passed to the decorated function:

```
 def wrap(*args,**kw): <- this is what is actually called when you invoke decorated function, no default values here
    print args, kw
    return func(*args,**kw) <- this is the function you decorate
    #if func has default parameter values, then those will be used 
    #when you don't pass them to the wrapper but only **inside** func
 return wrap
```

Edit:
It looks like you're mistaking calling the decorated function with decorating the function:

```
myfunc = dec(myfunc)
```

decorates `myfunc` using `dec` and is equivalent to

```
@dec
def myfunc(...)
```

On the other hand, after using either of them:

```
myfunc(whatever)
```

calls the `wrap` function defined in your decorator, which will in turn call the original `myfunc`

Comment: But how they were passed to the decorated function?

Comment: You passed them explicitly in `def wrap(*args,**kw):
        print args, kw
        return func(*args,**kw) <-- here`

Comment: Thank you, but `myfunc = dec(myfunc)` no arguments were metioned here.

Comment: Notice that you don't call `myfunc` here, just wrap (decorate) it using `dec`.

Comment: To call it, you still need to use `myfunc(...)` and you'll get the same results as when using `@dec`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm afraid I have taken up too much of your time. Thanks again.

Comment: Don' worry, that's what SO is for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are function wrappers. They give back a function that wraps the original one into some pre- and post-processing code, but still need to call the original function (normally with the same argument as you would call it in absence of a decorator).

Python has two types of arguments, positional and keyword arguments (this has nothing to do with decorators, that's generic python basics). `*` is for positional (internally is a list), `**` for keyword (dictionary) arguments. By specifying both you allow your decorator to accept all at all possible types of arguments and pass them through to the underlying function. The contract of the call is, however, still defined by your function. E.g. if it only takes keyword arguments it will fail when the decorator function passes through a positional argument.

In your particular example, you have some pre-processing code (i.e. code that will run before the original function is called). For example in this code you can print out arguments `*args` that your original function might fail to accept all together because it does not take any position arguments.

You do not necessarily have to pass through `*args` and `**kwargs`. In fact you can define a decorator which makes some decisions based on the arguments you pass in about what to provide to the original function as arguments, e.g.

```
def dec(fun):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'a' in kwargs:
            return fun(kwargs[a])
        else:
            return fun(*args)
    return wrap
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of it is by saying:

```
def wrapper(some_function):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        #do some work
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _inner

@wrapper
def foo(a, b, c):
    return "Foo called, and I saw %d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c)
```

...you're getting a result which is *roughly* similar to the following:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    #do some work
    return "Foo called, and I saw %d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c)
```

This isn't exactly right because the `#do some work` is occurring *before* the actual `foo()` call, but as an approximation this is what you're getting. For that reason, the wrapper can't really 'see' the default arguments for `foo()` if any exist. So a better way to think of it might be:

```
#always execute this code before calling...
def foo(a, b, c):
    return "Foo called and I saw %d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c)
```

So something really basic might look like this.

```
def wrap(f):
...     def _inner(*a, **k):
...             new_a = (ar*2 for ar in a)
...             new_k = {}
...             for k, v in k.iteritems():
...                     new_k[k] = v*2
...             return f(*new_a, **new_k)
...     return _inner
... 
>>> def foo(a=2, b=4, c=6):
...     return "%d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c)
... 
>>> foo()
'2, 4, 6'
>>> foo(1, 5, 7)
'1, 5, 7'
>>> foo = wrap(foo)    #actually wrapping it here
>>> foo()
'2, 4, 6'
>>> foo(3, 5, 6)
'6, 10, 12'
>>> foo(3, 5, c=7)
'6, 10, 14'
>>>
```